# passing the type argument to the generics

Tags: java, generics

```
public class G<x> {
  x i;
}

public class E {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    G<Integer> b1 = new G<Integer>();
    G<String> b2 = new G<String>();
    b1.i = 50;
    b2.i = "start";
    System.out.println(b1.i);
    System.out.println(b2.i);
  }
}
```

How this case is different from the other case given below

```
public class G<x> {
  x i;
}

public class E {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    G b1 = new G();
    G b2 = new G();
    b1.i = 50;
    b2.i = "start";
    System.out.println(b1.i);
    System.out.println(b2.i);
  }
}
```

I know While you are making the Object of G class we have to define the type argument for generics  but without passing the type argument it will work ..The output will be shown. 
So why my teacher says that Type argument is important though the code will run without it also.

There is a difference  in both cases. In first case we are passing an integer type argument  through the reference variable b1 and String  type argument through the b2 reference variable  but in the second case we are not doing this. And by not doing this In second case the  data type will be object type. Both code will give you same answer, but my teacher says that  you have to use always 1case .So my question was why he said so because both code will give you same answer so why cant we use  2 case

Answer (score 1):

I assume you actually mean this compiles:

```
G b1=new G();
G b2=new G();

b1.i=50;
b2.i="start";
System.out.println(b1.i);
System.out.println(b2.i);
```

This happens to work as `PrintStream.println` has an overload for `Object`, so will take any object. Usually you would want to call a more interesting method.

Incidentally there can still be a difference. Due to the peculiar design of `PrintStream`, this code will do something different.

```
G b1=new G();
G<char[]> b2=new G<>();

b1.i="start".toCharArray();
b2.i="start".toCharArray();
System.out.println(b1.i);
System.out.println(b2.i);
```

You will get warnings. Generally you want to treat warnings as if they were errors.

Comment: this code is way different from mine. In your  code the 2 line will give error but in my case you will not find any errors and exceptio while running the code

Comment: One more thing 
   G<char[]> b2=new G<char[]>();
by doing this you will get the result.
 what will this line b1.i="start".toCharArray(); give the output and why

Answer (score 0):

The first case is typesafe. 
In the first case you have declared that `b1.i` accepts only `Integer` so you can't by mistake assign i.e. `String` into it. You can rely on it containing `Integer`.

In the second case you can assign arbitrary descendant of Object into `b1.i` so typesafety is gone. You can't be so sure that `b1.i` contains particular type.